# How to set up facebook "like" button for status with photo

Tags: php, facebook

I've written a PHP script which adds in the Facebook Like buttons when it also prints out the statuses onto the website.

For normal statuses, the "like" button works fine, however, for posts with photos, the like button does not show the correct number of likes.

How should I go about fixing it?

The code sits in a loop, and uses the standard /pageID/posts call

```
                            print "<li>".(!empty($fb['picture']) ? "<a href=\"$fb[picture]\"><img src=\"$fb[picture]\" alt=\"".htmlspecialchars($fb['message'])."\" class=\"facebookItemImage\" ".(1==0 ? imageSize($fb['picture']) : "")." /></a><br />" : "").link_it($fb['message'])."<br />".($fb['type'] == "link" ? link_it($fb['link'])."<br />" : "")."<span class=\"facebookCreatedAt\">Posted ".getRelativeTime($fb['created_time']).(!empty($fb['place']) ? " from ".$fb['place']['name'] : "")."</span><br />
                                <div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"".(!empty($fb['picture']) ? $fb['picture'] : $fb['actions'][1]['link'])."\" data-send=\"false\" data-layout=\"button_count\" data-width=\"150\" data-show-faces=\"false\"></div></li>"."\n";
```

Comment: can you please provide us with a code? put it here or in text editor

Comment: I've edited in the code above.